# Send a slice of a Video File through HttpHandler

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming, httphandler

i am a .Net developer who has written a CMS-System for the Intranet of a specific company.
Our client has the ability to upload videos and other media there and let his employees and customers view them alongside other information.
We use a Standard Httphandler to fetch the uploaded video from HDD of the server and context.response.TransmitFile() it to the Browser.
So we can use this Handler as target for a html5  src-Attribute.
Now i've gotten a request to sort of "emulate" a videostream. The idea is that the client uplaods the video as a file, sets a specific start date from which the video should be viewable and every Request to the video should then return only the slice from the video from startdate to now.
Sort of pretending this video would be a live stream which goes forward on its own.

I tried adapting the HttpHandler to calculate the number of seconds between the startdate and the current request time, multiply it by the bitrate of the video and then simply cut off x bytes from the Stream (for example using Stream.seek) but the resulting data does not get recognized by Brwosers as a valid video stream. I guess this is because of missing (cut away) header-informations and key-frames etc.

Does anybody know a library who allows me to do this (cutting the video in slices *without* writing them to harddisk, i dont want to have a videofile laying around for every request thats landed on my httphandler)

The video is in mp4 format and i would liek to avoid the additional overhead of having to transcode it (like VLC requires when you use it for streaming)

Any ideas on this topic, im kinda lost...!?

Thanks in advance.
Chris

Clarification:
I do not know how much to cut off the video beforehand, that depends on the moment the stream is requested.
The Formula is easy: Date of the Request (Datetime.Now) - Configured Start time of the video. This Timespan has to be "skipped" from the start of the video.
Ideally i woudl like some library which allows me to load the file as a fileStream, skip x Seconds and write the remaining bytes/frames to the output of the httphandler. But i have no idea how to do this as VLC and FFMPEG seem so only support slicing by writing files, not giving me the sliced data as a stream...

Comment: Easiest would be to cut video right on upload. If original should be prrserved then save both original and cut version, and serve users only cut one. Doing that on the fly won't work without one or another overhead, at least it won't be easy to implement

Comment: I can not cut the video on upload because i do not know how much to cut off beforehand. foe Example: Video is uploaded today, start date set to tomorrow, 11 o'clock. if someone connects at 11:15, i have to cut off the first 15 minutes for him. another visitor connection 11:05 needs the video with only the fiorst 5 minutes cut away and so on.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood that. In such case you can convert video to for example HLS (codecs will likely stay they same if they are compatible), which by it's nature is chunked, and then manage which chunks are available when. You should be able to fake "live" streaming from static data using that.